# G Suite Marketplace “Integrate With Google” is not visible for new unpublished app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am developing G suite marketplace app. I have created new project and add G suite market place sdk as per google documentation. I do not see "Integrate With Google" in Configuration page for G Suite Marketplace SDK settings. Is there any thing to be done for this button to appear, so that I can test the app? Regards

Comment: I did some research and seen stack overflow questions regarding this. But could not get any answer that could solve my problem. On g suite market place help guide, it indicates that only way  to query is stack-overflow. I do not understand why this questions is down voted

Comment: I can take a look, can you tell me the cloud project number please? It's in the Configuration page.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your report. We have identified the problem and we are working on a solution.

Update: The issue has already been fixed.